# backbone design queries

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

In an MVC controller is what holds the business logic. In backbone the
controllers have been renamed to route. Now there are couple of things
which bring in confusion.

1. Model should have business logic.
2. Collection is the collection of models.
3. Views are where the templates are rendered, and most of the DOM
   event handling is done.
4. Apart from routing, what do the routers do? And where should more
   of business logic go to the routers or to the models?

Do the views perform anything extra other than rendering DOM
variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes they should, also should be the ones with a "link" to the Backend, to do the CRUD, but can also validate object state, ensure backend and frontend model sync and other things.
2. Correct again, but they also have a very nice use that is to fetch lists of models from the server very easily.
3. They should also attach event handlers to HTML elements and models and react to those events accordingly.

4.They handle all URL changing events and direct them to display the proper views for that URL, routers give you the opportunity to change your page completely and keep track of the URL changes by using Backbone.history, so Back and Forward Browser buttons will keep working.

They do the URL mapping.

It's an awesome framework, I can't live without it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

- You don't need to use routers et all, if you use them the should just route.
- Views should contain all the DOM/Model-Event listeners.
- Some Ideas on structuring: http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/